# TreeItem of material-ui to be focused by right-clicking

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

Please teach me how to control the background color when right-clicking on TreeView/TreeItem.
Based on https://codesandbox.io/s/jggxz?file=/demo.tsx which is linked from https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/ ,
in the case of implementing the context menu function, the background color of the right-clicked item is not as expected.

Let me explain how it works by watching the attached video.
[image]

Right-click on "Forums" to bring up the context menu.
Then, for a brief moment, "Forums" will get the focus and the background color will change to pink.
After the background color disappears, the context menu will appear.
Also, up to this point, the background color of "Promotions", which was selected from the beginning, is always green.

What I want is the following. What should I do to make it look like the following?
Right-click on "Forums" to bring up the context menu.
Then the background color of the right-clicked item "Forums" will change to green, and
at the same time, the background color of the selected "Promotions" from the beginning will disappear.

Another thing I tried was to use TreeView's "selected" props and useState, but it did not work as expected.
That version is below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h5z8e?file=/demo.tsx